# Load many shapefiles into PostgreSQL with GeoKettle

Tags: geokettle

I want to automate a process where a user can put a shapefile in a certain map. Kettle will put these files into a PostgreSQL table.

I want to make sure that this process can be done without knowing the name of the shapefile. I tried two different methods.

1. I dragged Shapefile File Input into the transformation and put the extension at *.shp. This didn't work.

[image]

2. I made a CSV file input with a CSV file with 1 column and the path plus the name of the shapefile. In the Shapefile File Input I insert that Filename as defined in a field from a previous step.

[image]

Although it looks like everything is read properly, I cannot furthermore do transformations like set SRS or put it in a PostgreSQL table, because it cannot receive any fields from previous steps.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try scripting it?